# Jmeter report got unfinished data

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

hello im a newbie who trying learn and use Jmeter, i have a question
when im run my jmeter scripti got a data that seems like not finish yet, like in the picture, so when i try to make dashboard report it always said "cannot error errorlevel=1"

[this how the report looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDDJf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround you can just delete this "problematic" line with the incomplete metrics.

With regards to the reason - it looks like that JMeter test has been terminated abnormally, check out [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file for any suspicious entries.

Looking into column "M" - `allThreads` it seems that you're running the test with 2800+ virtual users, it might be the case you need to follow recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article and if JMeter still lacks resources consider going for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html).